# Image wrapped in link overlapped by another floating link in Firefox only, Chrome and IE fine

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a navigation bar that is proportionaly scaling its size on page resize:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="breadcrumbs">
        <div class="breadcrumbs-insert">
            <a href="#"><img src=
            "http://i.imgur.com/1gLVM1T.png"></a>
            <a href="#">Text 1</a>
            <span>Text 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
#breadcrumbs {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 2.5%;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-size: 0.35em;
        font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light', "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        background: #0073b5;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .breadcrumbs-insert {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #breadcrumbs span {
        line-height: 100%;
        height: 72%;
        padding-top: 0.7%;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        padding-right: 2.08333%;
        padding-left: 2.08333%;
        background: #39a9d1;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #breadcrumbs a {
        line-height: 100%;
        height: 72%;
        padding-top: 0.7%;
        float: left;
        display: block;
        padding-right: 1.04166%;
        padding-left: 1.04166%;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;

    }

    #breadcrumbs img {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #breadcrumbs a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
        background: #39a9d1;
    }

    #breadcrumbs a:hover, a:active {
        background: #39a9d1;
    }

    #breadcrumbs a:first-of-type {
        margin-left: 1.04166%;
        padding-left: 0.26041%;
        padding-right: 0.26041%;
        height: 100%;
        padding-top: 0;
    }

    #breadcrumbs a:last-of-type {
        padding-right: 2.08333%;
    }
```

Here is the fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/acidonyx/m4ahtuLv/4/)

For some reason in Firefox first link wrapping the image is overlapped by the next floating link. Chrome and IE working fine.

Been trying to figure it out for hours now and finally giving up...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an unordered list for your nav instead.

html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="url">text 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="url">text 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
  ul li { 
  display: inline; 
  list-style-type: none;
  }
```

Not sure if that's what you are trying to do, but that fixed the issue for me in your example.